# Is there any events based calendar that is available for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, events, calendar

Hi i am looking for an  events calendar where user can come in and add their events.. and then latter on other ppl can view it...

what i am looking for is something like this..

http://www.torontoparentsguide.com/Events/tabid/92/Default.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what kind of functionality you're looking for.

[DayPilot](http://www.daypilot.org/) is a good solution if you want a calendar API that you can develop your own back-end for.

If you want just a "stand-alone" application then [VCalendar](http://www.ultraapps.com/app_overview.php?app_id=19) is a better solution.

Both are open source, but depending on your needs, it will be easier to work with one or the other.